# Simplest way to find a class by a string in python

Tags: python, class

```
getattr(importlib.import_module(__name__), "Some Class")
```

This is my method.
But this is redundant.
Is there a simpler method?
I use django and I'm trying to pass a dict of model to other class whose name is same as model name.
Roughly, this is my code.
I want to do this without if statement.

```
instance_list = []
obj_list = [a,b,c,d]
for obj in obj_list:
    dic = model_to_dict(obj)
    if 'Soccer' == obj.__class__.__name__:
        instance_list.append(Soccer(dic))
    elif 'Tennis' == obj.__class__.__name__:
        instance_list.append(Tennis(dic))
```

Comment: You should explain what you are doing and why. "Finding a class by a string" is not something you would normally need to do.

Comment: If the point is to get the name of the class `"Some Class"` it looks like you already have it don't you ?

Comment: Sorry both, my code was wrong..  I fixed it and added more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the point is to have a module function that returns a class *from the same module* by it's name, you could indeed rewrite it in a much less convoluted way:

```
# mymodule.py
class Foo(object):
    pass

def get_class(name):
    return globals()[name]


# main.py
import mymodule
print(mymodule.get_class("Foo"))
```

Note that depending on your use case it might be safer to use an explicit dict of classes that are allowed to be looked up by `mymodule.get_class()`. You may really want to consider this option if the class name comes from user inputs and you know exactly which classes should be allowed.

Also note that for Django models classes you could also use `apps.get_model(app_name, model_name)` which lets you get models from any app.

Comment: @mtdkki if this solves your problem then feel free to accept (and eventually upvote) the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get something (not necessarily a class) from the current module by name:

```
this_module = sys.modules[__name__]
cls = getattr(this_module, "SomeClass")
```

Comment: Your answer is also useful. Thank you:)